# git (Bitbucket) pushing folder from another repo: loose object is corrupt

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

**So I have downloaded the git project via ftp, and now I need to push it to another Bitbucket repository.**

I have successfully changed the remote origin, but I cannot push data, because I'm getting the error

```
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid distance too far back)
fatal: loose object fd4ae5129374c0e151be6e60e2e3d2d0f134f738 (stored in .git/objects/fd/4ae5129374c0e151be6e60e2e3d2d0f134f738) is corrupt
```

The problem is that I'm pushing the project to the repo for the first time, but it was a different repo before, so I have logs in .git folder and thousands of objects.

What should I do to somehow clear the .git history so I could be able to just push everything to my repo? Would highly appreciate any possible help!

Comment: Instead of downloading, first clone the project, After that remove origin and add new origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just deleted the .git folder and then used `git init` again

Comment: That's not a good solution. Now you have no history in common with the original repository. If you ever want to share commits between the two (e.g. to pull in new changes from the original, or commit patches back upstream) you're going to find it doesn't work.